# Ouput yes/no in commerce product table if product image available/not available

Tags: views, commerce

I am using Drupal 7 together with Drupal Commerce (not Kickstart). I am using a Bootstrap theme.

I have list of products displayed in a table that I created with Views. If you click on the Title, it goes to the product content page (display). Obviously, a product has an image if one is available. What I would want to do is to have a column in the table (Image), that would print out Yes or No, depending on if the image is uploaded (available) for the product.

Is this something that can be done in Drupal?

Comment: Do want to display Yes/No in the table or product display page?

Comment: In the table that shows the list of all product.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply add your image field. When you add it, or if you click on it if you already added it, you will see something similar to the following date field screenshot.

[image]

- Click on rewrite results and put "Yes" here.
- Click on no results behavior and put "No" here.

---

> Is there a way to solve this in a similar way if you have a default
>   image set - if none is uploaded a default image shows up?

In this scenario you would have to use [Image URL Formatter](https://www.drupal.org/project/image_url_formatter) and set the view image field formatter to display url.

Then you would simply perform a conditional check to see if the URL is equal to the default image url either using Views template file & custom code OR alternatively using [Views Conditional](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_conditional) for a zero coding solution.

Comment: Thanks. This sounds like an elegant solution. Is there a way to solve this in a similar way if you have a default image set - if none is uploaded a default image shows up?

Comment: @prima, hehe forgot about that, just added a solution for that scenario to my answer.